# Cannot give profile read access to custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-profile

When I try to edit a profile to give read writes to a custom object it complains about not having rights to other objects but I cannot go to those objects and give the rights either as it complains about other objects putting me in a circle

I simply tried to change tab settings from 'Tab Hidden' to 'Default Off' and check the object permissions box for 'Read' rights

I get errors like this? Why and how do I give rights when it won't let me?
Please fix the following:

```
Permission Create FedEx Queued Export Details depends on permission(s): Read FedEx Bulk Shipments
Permission Create FedEx Queued International Commodities depends on permission(s): Read FedEx Bulk Shipments
Permission Create FedEx Queued Shipment Documents depends on permission(s): Read FedEx Bulk Shipments
Permission Delete FedEx Queued Export Details depends on permission(s): Read FedEx Bulk Shipments
Permission Delete FedEx Queued International Commodities depends on permission(s): Read FedEx Bulk Shipments
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Such error on profile happens when you are on the enhanced profile view page as you can only open one object's setting at a time.

You can fix this error by switching the profile view to the old style using setup and try giving the access to all related objects at a time and that should solve the problem.

> **Steps to get old profile view**

Setup > User Management Settings > Enhanced Profile User Interface (Disabled)

Comment: Thank you Nishant Singh Panwar. That worked perfectly. Sincerely appreciate your quick and accurate response